# discord.py rewrite | Making errors for my commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Now that I finished my moderation commands [mostly], I am trying to add errors in. I already made the "please specify a member" error, but I cannot manage to make the bot say "this member does not exist" when an invalid name is input.

```
@client.command(name='kick',
            brief='Kicks user',
            aliases=['Kick'],
            pass_context=True)
async def kick(context, member:discord.Member=None):
# Errors
if not member:
    await context.send('Please specify a member.')
    return
# Actual Kicking
if context.author.guild_permissions.kick_members == True:
    await member.kick()
    await context.send(f"{member.mention} was kicked ")
else:
    await context.send(context.message.author.mention + ", you don't have permission")
```

This is one of my commands, where everything is working. I would like an error which says "User not found" if the member, obviously, doesn't exist. For example, `k!kick ijhguiserb` would make the bot say, "Member not found," rather than giving me an error in the shell.

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to define an [error handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) to handle the `ConversionError`

```
from discord.ext.commands import ConversionError

@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, (ConversionError, BadArgument)):
        await ctx.send("Member not found")
    else:
        raise error
```

Comment: I put this into my code, however nothing changed. Could you know why?

Comment: Update, after a bit of thinking i came up with: `elif isinstance(error, BadArgument):
        await ctx.send('Member not found')`, which made the bot tell me the member was not found. Thanks for the link, it will help me fix more of this stuff! :)